# How long should I wait for the response of the referee?

Tags: research-process, publications, thesis

i wrote a message to the Editor to inquire about my
revision sent about 4 months ago.  He informed me yesterday(March 20th, 2014)
that my manuscript has already completed 1 review.
However, we are still awaiting the last report.
from the remaining referee. My question is How long
should I wait for the response of the referee? and what do you advise me to do?
n.b. the journal belongs to Springer
Best regards

Comment: What's your field? It's relevant information.

Comment: @scaahu: Indeed. If it's mathematics, my advice would be "just keep waiting, this is normal".

Comment: Yes, keep waiting! What I usually do when I choose a journal is look at some (recent) papers. Usually they have a short "history" like first submission, revisions, and the date when it was accepted. But 6 months waiting period is nothing unusual. Esp. if the field is pretty narrow and reviewers scarce.

Comment: 4 months is, unfortunately, not very long in some domains. I'd be over the moon if reviews were done that fast in my domain.

Comment: I am seismologist

Comment: 4 months for secondary revision is too long no??

Comment: This is probably something you should be asking people working in your field. When I'm submitting, I usually ask the journal what their expected turnaround for reviews is. That way (in theory) I get a bit of a heads up.

Answer (score 3):

> i wrote a message to the Editor to inquire about my revision sent about 4 months ago. He informed me yesterday(March 20th, 2014) that my manuscript has already completed 1 review.

Since you have contacted the editor and they looked into it (and perhaps pinged the reviewer with a reminder), I don't see that there is much else you could do at this point (other than something drastic like withdraw, which would be entirely unjustified after four months).

> However, we are still awaiting the last report. from the remaining referee. My question is How long should I wait for the response of the referee?

As long as it takes.

> and what do you advise me to do?

You've just contacted the editor and gotten a response. My advice now would simply be to be patient. Try to put it at the back of your mind and focus on other work. (And don't message the editor again for another few months; have faith in them to do their job.)

> 4 months for secondary revision is too long no??

In many fields, unfortunately, no.